# WhDatePicker style is not working if we have cjuidautocomplete on same form

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, yii, datepicker

I am having a style issue with WhDatePicker.When we use Cjuiautocomplete on the same form with WhDatePicker then the Style of datepicker is not loaded properly. 
I tried to remove the Jquery-Ui.css but then Autocomplete style is not working. How can we resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fix to this right now except manually overwriting the CJui CSS files after putting them in a name scope as pointed out by Mihai P.

Or you can do this, the CSS files which loads in the end wins the class precedence.
So you can write your code something like :-

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'name'=>'city',
    'source'=>array('ac1','ac2','ac3'),
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;',
    ),
));

$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.datepicker.WhDatePicker', array(
    'name' => 'datepickertest',
    'pluginOptions' => array(
        'format' => 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    )
));
```

Call the autocomplete first so that the CSS files from YiiWheel's Datepicker are loaded in the last.

Comment: Good answer! This should be put as an issue in the yii wheels github page.

Comment: This is not a fix, it is a trick. What happens when you need to insert another control too that uses another style sheet, put them in the exact order so they do not overwrite each other again? Anyway glad to see people are linking this answer although it promotes bad habbits.

Comment: I myself said that there is no fix to it right now, and changing the internal files of Yii is always discouraged. So until the developers themselves change it, we should go with the trick :P

Comment: I have arised this issue on official Github repo.Hope they will resolve soon, thanks guys for your help
https://github.com/2amigos/yiiwheels/issues/98
Still not getting any resolution

Comment: Sure, teach people how to make stupid tricks instead of normal practices. And of course they go ahead and make an "issue" instead of understanding what/why this is happening.

Comment: Actually please keep them dumb with tricks like this, make them make "issues". And Sudhanshu please keep pushing with the issue, it is basically a major bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @MihaiP. Why so jealous bro/sis? Do you even know how many problems do you have to face if you modify the internals of Yii? How're you supposed to update and keep your site running again? And on top of that you should not even change the plugins, because if you had to modify a plugin only then you should sit and write the whole plugin from scratch yourself and submit it.

Comment: Dude, you do not have to modify the internals of Yii, what are you crazy? it is a CSS file that we are talking about... This question is "I have a css file that is overwritten by another css file" just the author has no idea cause it is the first time he used Yii. Why on earth would you modify Yii to handle this? Anyway... no more comments.. I see who I am dealing with. You are right...keep up the good work.

Comment: @MihaiP. I know that we have to modify the CSS file and not a PHP file. Okay sir/mam, please do tell that when we overwrite this CSS file with a CSS file which is having this scope, okay, now when you call a Widget from Yii. It will fetch the CSS file and PHP widget won't have any information about the scope in that file. It will try to implement the normal classes and then you'll be rendered useless with no CSS Widget. How are you going to deal with it without changing the plugin or internals of Yii?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the styles in jquery ui overwrite the styles in your page, resulting in the cjui not showing using the correct styles. Use a scope for jquery ui to make only a specific part of the page show using those styles.
http://filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/
http://devcoma.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/how-to-use-jquery-ui-theme-with-other.html